# Is it allowed to use cone plastic megaphone in Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat

Is it allowed to use cone plastic megaphone in Shabbat? It is a cone like plastic that magnify your voice. It does not include any electrical devices. Can a child (under 13) use it? Can a Chazan use it in Shabbat? Here is an example for [it](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/335113237365).